# Pooled OLS: how to correct for serial correlation of residuals

Tags: r, panel-data, autocorrelation, pooling, clustered-standard-errors

I am trying to follow the procedure offered by [Beck and Katz 1995](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2082979?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) in a way that I also have a TSCS data with $T=100$ (time dimension) and $N=12$ (unit dimension). My data is not balanced, which means that for some time periods, not all units have observations.

I am using R, and I found a `pcse` package that does what I need. It calculates panel corrected standard errors which accounts for contemporaneous correlation of errors across units and unit level heteroskedasity of errors. However, the steps I have to take to calculate panel robust standard errors for this type of regression start with the need to correct for serial correlation of errors, if I understand it well. Particularly, that is what is recommended in `pcse` package documentation:

[image]

So, I am lost trying to understand what I need to do. My options how I see them:

1. Run simple OLS regression on my pooled panel data.
2. Test for serial correlation of error term using Durbin–Watson test and examining ACF/PACF. In most cases, I will have AR(1) in errors.

   - Either compute clustered standard errors - it should account for the fact that errors should be clustered on the unit variable. After this step, I would get robust standard errors, but I cannot use it in pcse estimation - I don't need the VCV of errors as an input for the `pcse` function, but the OLS `lm` object itself.
   - Or use Cochrane–Orcutt transformation first, and then use transformed  model as an input for pcse estimation. I started doing it, but realized that after CO transformation, error term became serially independent, but had the kurtosis of 20 (normality assumption fails).

So, my options are not so suitable. How do you think I should approach this situation?